# ModalViewController dismissed automatically

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I present a ModalViewController which uses CLLocationManagerDelegate first time in my app so that I get the AlertView if determination of the location is allowed.

After pressing any button in alert, the ModalViewController gets dismissed. No delegate methods gets called so that I can see, who is dismissing the view.

Any ideas how to find the dismissing caller?

**EDIT:**
Found out, that when iOS asks for permission the application goes to background. When my app goes to background it shows an empty screen for security reasons. This releases my modal view controller.

Comment: you can add breakpoint to -[UIViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:] if it is modal

Comment: -[UIViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:] doesn't get called. thats the thing that makes me wondering.